# Configuring a portlet has three different names

Tags: websphere-portal

When i include a portlet in a page, i'm asked to customize the portlet.

Trying to do so, i have three options namely:

1. Edit Shared settings
2. Personalize &
3. Configure

What does each mean and How do they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old page but it still describes the differences correctly: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc/wps/adcfgplt.html

In short:

- Configure: Changes made here affect all occurrences of the portlet on all pages for all users. The administration portlets allow you to create multiple copies of the same portlet with different administrator level configurations.
- Edit Shared: Changes made here affect a particular instance of a portlet on a page and apply to all users who view that instance of the portlet on that page.
- Personalize: Changes made here are associated with a single user and apply only to that particular user who views the portlet on the page. Only that user can make that update.